# Best practice for altering animated class after ajax in javascript

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I have an application that performs an ajax request and sets a class on an element, which in turns changes the background colour and does a small scale transform.  I'm using Vue.js and the `erroredSave` property is the property that sets the class.

The relevant code is as such:

```
this.erroredSave = false

this.$http.post('some/url/', params)
.then((data) => {
    // ALL GOOD
})
.catch((errors) => {
     this.erroredSave = true
})
```

If I perform the process over and over, the animation often doesn't take place because the request performs very quickly and I think JS doesn't have the time it requires to unset the class completely.  I think...

I have to set a small timeout delay before I perform the request or the css animation won't take place.

So my code ends up as:

```
this.erroredSave = false

setTimeout(() => {
    this.$http.post('some/url', params)
    .then((data) => {
        // ALL GOOD
    })
    .catch((errors) => {
        this.erroredSave = true
    })
}, 10)
```

I'm not sure why the setTimeout is required.  Can anyone tell me why?  Is there a standard/better practice for this type of thing?

**EDIT**

SCSS for the error elements.  This is actually performed on table rows if that makes any difference.

```
&.error_row
{
    background: linear-gradient(#ffe0e0 10%, #ffcccc 100%) !important;
    animation: scaleSuccess 0.25s linear;
    transform-origin: center center;
    color: $red;

    @keyframes scaleSuccess {
        50%
        {
            transform: scale(1.05);
        }

        100%
        {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The animations do fire upon first cal.  However, any additional calls that result in errors require the small timeout to see the animations perform.

Comment: Has this worked at all?  Maybe I'm just rusty on arrow functions, but wouldn't `this` be bound to the wrong object?  Try capturing a variable that points to `this` outside of the catch and then use that capture variable in the catch callback.

Comment: @zero298: No; arrow functions capture the right `this`.

Comment: Its the sense of arrow functions not to have an own context. They always have the lexical context.

Comment: Slaks is correct.  Can you post the CSS for the animation and can you check whether the animation is actually firing using your developer tools?  Chrome has an animation debugger, I'm not sure about FireFox.

Comment: I've added the relevant SCSS to my question.  My apologies for not doing so previously!

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me once, the solution was to use `transitions` instead of `animations`.

when you remove/add animations the change will happen abruptly, but with transitions they will take whatever css value is currently being applied to your element -even if it happens in the middle of another transition-, start from there and transition to your intended css final value.

so for example if you are changing the background color before the ajax request and then changing it again at the end of it like this:

```
$(".ajax-call").click(function(event){
    $('body').removeClass().addClass("ajax-ongoing");
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data : { json: JSON.stringify( jsonData ) },
    success: function(data) {
      $('body').addClass("ajax-success");
    } 
  });
});
```

you can set your css classes with a transition and a transition delay like this:

```
body{
  background-color: white;
}
body.ajax-ongoing{
  background-color: orange;
}

body.ajax-success{
  transition-delay: 1s;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in;
  background-color: green;
}
```

you can see a live [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/d5y9pp3L/)

Transitions will work well with your transform: scale(n) also.